# Actionscript 3.0 problem - Why is it giving an error even when I've re-checked the code?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using Adobe Flash CS4 professional for this Actionscript 3.0 project
(http://tutorials.flashmymind.com/2009/02/rotating-menu-via-actionscript-3/)

I even tried following the suggestions in the comments as well but this error always shows up: 
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at rotating_menu_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
(for complete details, kindly click the link - http://i429.photobucket.com/albums/qq19/tsujzpie/screenshot_03.jpg)

I've been following every step of the tutorial but I'm stumped over the coding...
Here's the code by the way...

```
//Save the center coordinates of the stage
var centerX:Number=stage.stageWidth/2;
var centerY:Number=stage.stageHeight/2;
 //The number of items we will have (feel free to change!)
var NUMBER_OF_ITEMS:uint=5;
 //Radius of the menu circle (horizontal and vertical)
var radiusX:Number=200;
var radiusY:Number=100;
 //Angle difference between the items (in radians)
var angleDifference:Number = Math.PI * (360 / NUMBER_OF_ITEMS) / 180;
 //How fast a single circle moves (we calculate the speed
//according to the mouse position later on...)
var angleSpeed:Number=0;
 //Scaling speed of a single circle
var scaleSpeed:Number=0.0002;
 //This vector holds all the items
//(this could also be an array...)
var itemVector:Array = new Array ('1', '2', '3', '4','5');
 //This loop creates the items and positions them
//on the stage
for (var i:uint = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ITEMS; i++) {
    //Create a new menu item
    var item:Item = new Item();
    //Get the angle for the item (we space the items evenly)
    var startingAngle:Number=angleDifference*i;
    //Set the x and y coordinates
    item.x=centerX+radiusX*Math.cos(startingAngle);
    item.y=centerY+radiusY*Math.sin(startingAngle);
    //Save the starting angle of the item.
    //(We have declared the Item class to be dynamic. Therefore,
    //we can create new properties dynamically.)
    item.angle=startingAngle;
    //Add an item number to the item's text field
    item.itemText.text=i.toString();
    //Allow no mouse children
    item.mouseChildren=false;
    //Add the item to the vector
    itemVector.push(item);
    //Add the item to the stage
    addChild(item);
}
 //We use ENTER_FRAME to animate the items
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
 //This function is called in each frame
function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void {
    //Calculate the angle speed according to mouse position
    angleSpeed = -(mouseX - centerX) / 5000;
    //Loop through the vector
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ITEMS; i++) {
        //Save the item to a local variable
        var item:Item=itemVector[i];
        //Update the angle
        item.angle+=angleSpeed;
        //Set the new coordinates
        item.x=centerX+radiusX*Math.cos(item.angle);
        item.y=centerY+radiusY*Math.sin(item.angle);
        //Calculate the vertical distance from centerY to the item
        var dy:Number=centerY-item.y;
        //Scale the item according to vertical distance
        item.scaleY = (dy / radiusY)+2;
        //Set the x scale to be the same as y scale
        item.scaleX=item.scaleY;
        //Adjust the alpha according to y scale
        item.alpha=item.scaleY+1.1;
    }
}
```

I find it odd - it may be that the code is right but I don't know if these steps has messed up the project...

```
3 - Convert the circle into a movie clip... 
4 - In the “Item” movie clip, create a dynamic text field in the center of the circle (in a     new layer).
5 - Set the text to align center. Type some number in the text field. Give the text field an instance name of “itemText”. Embed numerals...
6 - Remove the Item movie clip from the stage. We will create all the items dynamically via ActionScript 3.
```

I could've given more screenshots but since I'm a new user, I'm only allowed a max of two - and contrary to this tag, I'm not doing an Android app. 
(I'll give you added info once any of you would reply to this question...)

I have to admit that the steps 3 to 6 is confusing and didn't made sense to me - especially with step six, when you have to remove the movie clip from the stage. For me, if I were to do that, what would the script work on then?

Any idea what I did wrong?

EDIT:
Thanks, I realized my mistake - thanks for the tip :-)

But now, I tried to modify the code of this tutorial a bit to have words appear inside the circles (like "Home", "About", etc....) like what I've typed in the line in the screenschot - http://i429.photobucket.com/albums/qq19/tsujzpie/modifiedlineincode_00.jpg

But inspite of what I believe are the appropriate changes I've done, an error showed up still - (kindly see here - http://i429.photobucket.com/albums/qq19/tsujzpie/newerrorincode_00.jpg)

Why is that happening? Before I forget, in what section of the code must I insert a line that will make a clicked button display the info corresponding to it? (that is, if I click on the "Contact" or any of the buttons a window will appear beneath the menu on the stage...)

Answer (score 3):

That errors means ActionScript has no clue what an Item is. Make sure you've ticked Export for ActionScript on your Item MovieClip in library and that the class is named Item also.

**Update:**
The tutorial you're following mentions itemVector is a Vector of Item instances, **not** an array of Strings like you're code suggests. This why you're getting the error displayed in your screenshot. It means ActionScript can not convert an Item to a String. 
An easy fix is to create another array for the menu item labels:

```
var itemVector:Array = [];// = new Array ('1', '2', '3', '4','5');
var itemLabels:Array = ["Home","About","Contact","Gallery"];
NUMBER_OF_ITEMS = itemLabels.length;
```

and in the for loop swap this `item.itemText.text=i.toString();` for this `tem.itemText.text=itemLabels[i];`

It seems that you don't fully grasp the difference between variable types. I would suggest getting familiar with the basics of as3 before moving forward. Also paying more attention to your code and fully understanding code you use written by others will keep you out of trouble. However you will still encounter errors. You might find explanations for those errors on the [Flash Error Database](http://www.actionscripterrors.com/).

Regarding the Carosel tutorial, also have a look at [this video](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=32). It might help explain things better.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - but kindly refer below your reply for other details - ran into new problems again... :-(

Comment: @Flash_flea Check my updated answer. Also, your notes should've been a comment not an answer.

Comment: Well, I was desperate for a way to be heard with my other concerns - the site has too many limits for newly registered users. Thanks for the hints :-)

Comment: Glad that sort it out. Feel free to tick/accept this answer if you deem it helpful ;)

Comment: I want to ask three things:                                        1) I noticed in the video you referred to me (http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=32)as for Flash 8 versions only - would the code there work with AS3 as well? 
2) The video didn't show how to cause a button to open up a frame or window on the stage. How would one pull that off?
3) Part 2 of the video shows how to put mouse events only for Flash movies embedded in XML pages - since that may cause cross-browser display problems, do you know how to make the code used there compatible for all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can not find the Item class.
Go into your library and open up the properties for the "Item" MovieClip.
Verify that is is set for export to actionscript.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - but kindly refer above your reply for other details - ran into new problems again... :-(

Comment: @Flash_Flea The idea of this site is to ask a question and get an answer and then accept it. When you modify your question and ask another question it becomes increasing more difficult to follow your issues at hand. What you need to do is if one of the answers here worked, than accept it, and than move on to a new question. Post a new thread for a new issue.